# Docusign Connect Setting on Dashboard

Tags: docusignapi

I tried to set the DocuSign Connect thru the dashboard. A custom one

URL to publish to: to the url

and other settings

but when I try to save it seems like nothing happened.

I cant find the one I just set.

Comment: Are you seeing other connect configurations for your account?

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?  Which UI are you using, the new UI or Classic UI?  (Note: If you click on your profile in the top right of your developer sandbox account and you see the link "switch to classic" that means you are using the New UI.  You can switch back and forth.)

Answer (score 0):

here are a couple of resources to help with Connect Configurations:

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custom-connect-configuration-htm

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect

Note that you need to go to the DocuSign Admin to make changes and see your configurations (which requires you to be an admin of the DocuSign Account)